# mod_rewrite; subdomain & subdir

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain

www.mydomain.com = main website

m.mydomain.com is a virtual site which maps to www.mydomain.com/m/

I have a .htaccess inside root (for the main site) & also another .htaccess in /m/ to show nice urls, all is fine up to this point.

Now here is the issue: the shopping basket (m.mydomain.com/basket/) will post to

https://www.mydomain.com/m/checkout/

so that the SSL cert is valid. It does not matter that the URL will change from m.domain.com at this point.

I am confused because if i write a .htaccess rule in the root...

```
RewriteRule ^m/checkout/?$ m/checkout_m.php
```

& visit https://www.mydomain.com/m/checkout/
Then the /m/ directory sees this as an 404 error.

If i place a rule in the /m/ directory...

```
RewriteRule ^checkout/?$ checkout_m.php
```

& visit the secure url as above
Then the main site sees it as an 404 error. (I know this because m. & www. have different 404 pages)

If I activate both rules, it still fails. So having trouble working out which has priority in this situation & how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have enabled the RewriteEngine

```
RewriteEngine ON
```

**EDIT**

The problem is that there is a real directory named 'm', this seems to confuse the webserver.

Comment: /? simply means that a trailing slash in the URL is optional.
So domain.com/checkout & domain.com/checkout/ are both acceptable variations.

Comment: idd, correct, still early here :) I just took a look in .htaccess files I have working here. Have you enabled the RewriteEngine?

Comment: yes - as i say, its all working except the part where i access the subdomain via the main url

Comment: maybe the webserver is confused because there is a real /m/ directory? I'm just guessing here, but can you change the rewrite rule to `^test/checkout$ m/checkout_m.php` then browse to [https://www.mydomain.com/test/checkout](https://www.mydomain.com/m/checkout)

Comment: that works. it might be a good workaround - thanks. I will modify the checkout to accept /mobile/ rather than /m/ & test further.

Comment: Accepting because it solves the issue for me, thanks. I suspect there is another way, but this is good enough.

Comment: Which webserver are you using anyway?